# ERP System using pure Angular and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

Is it possible to create an ERP system using pure angular and firebase without any backend scripting languages and/or frameworks ?

Comment: It is a very valid question and helps people to make serious decisions. Couldn't say that someone could find more frustrating moderators in any other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes of course, using the real-time database instead of MySql, mariadb, mongodb ... using the firebase SDK instead of backend languages.

Comment: wouldn't that be unsafe ? dont know why I have this stereotype about this approach lol

Comment: sorry for late answer it's totally safe, using uuid as keys and the authentication module, the database rules ... and more

Comment: @OussemaAroua but how do you gonna do a routine that calc something being safe? Ex: Calc your salary